# Filter By Id in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

I get problem with filter data when i using where condition the data not show in the table or page.

I have three tables **Groups** , **Subgroups** , **Students**

First i select the group then i select subgroup and from subgroup students table show

**this is my controller:**

```cs
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var students = db.Students.AsQueryable()
        .Include(s => s.Groups)
        .Include(s => s.Subgroups)
        .Include(s => s.Schedules)
        .Include(s => s.Teachers);

    if (id != null)
    {
        students = students
            .Where(s => s.SubgroupId == id).Where(s => s.GroupId == id);
    }

    ViewBag.result = students;
    return View(students.ToList());
}
```

**Group Class:**

```cs
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Subgroup Class:**

```cs
public class Subgroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

**Student class:**

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Groups { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubgroupId")]
    public virtual Subgroup Subgroups { get; set; }
    public int? SubgroupId { get; set; }
}
```

when i delete **groupId** the data show but the group data not filter so all group show .

I do not know what is the mistake

Thank you

Comment: The `id` parameter, is it a group id or a subgroup id ?

Comment: for the both it is wrong ?

Comment: Will you include your model classes?

Comment: I add can check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're filtering twice, try filtering once :

```cs
if (id != null)
{
    students = students
        .Where(s => s.SubgroupId == id && s.GroupId == id);
}
```

Also, if in your model/app the `Student` can belong to a group and a subgroup whose group is different from the student's group (which is very likely) then you need to remove the `Group` foreign key/property from the `Student` entity because you can always access the `Group` from the `Subgroup` property.

Comment: I get this error 
Error The name 's' does not exist in the current context 

Error Syntax error, ','

Comment: @programmer check again